# Is it possible to miss $(document).ready?

Tags: jquery, preload

Let's say you're loading a bunch of super heavy images with a js preloader ([Preload.JS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS)) and in the callback you have your $(document).ready function.

Example code:

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue();

queue.loadManifest([
    "img/1.jpg",
    "img/2.jpg",
    "img/3.png"
]);

queue.on("complete", preloadComplete, this);

function preloadComplete() {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        //jquery stuff
    });
}
```

Is it possible that the preloading could take so long that the ready function gets missed?

Comment: Note that you are only attaching the event handler when preloadComplete runs, if it never runs, it will never be called.

Comment: If the document is ready by the time the parser hits the DOM ready handler, it's immediately executed, so no, it can't be missed, it's always executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ready function can't be *"missed"*. Even if the document is already ready, the function within it will run.

http://api.jquery.com/ready

> If .ready() is called after the DOM has been initialized, the new handler passed in will be executed immediately.

Comment: You can try this by executing with Firebug or similar something like this: `$(document).ready(function() {alert("test");})`. It will be execute like `alert("test");`